# itunes 11 - Resize window problem

Tags: itunes, applications

iTunes will not let me resize the window at my leisure. I tried going into /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj, and then opening the file AppConfig.plist, but it will not let me change it, what I can do?

Comment: HOLA Jose, in English please :)

Comment: **Translation:** iTunes will not let me resize the window at my leisure. I tried going into `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj`, and then opening the file `AppConfig.plist`, but it will not let me change it, what I can do?

Comment: Hi Borderline, thanks for your comment, next time in english, no worries.  ;)